How to extract data from json column in my dataset in Big Query
I'm working in Big Query. My dataset has a column with json data. I'd like to extract the elements within the array as separate columns with string values.
A single row of data on my column payment attributes consists of [{"name": "Invoice Number", "value": "27224 & 27225"}, {"name": "Account Number", "value": "TEST01"}]
If I do:
select JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(payment_attributes) as json_payment_attributes
from table

I get the array broken out like this



Row
json_payment_attributes




1
{"name":"Invoice Number","value":"27224 & 27225"}


1
{"name":"Account Number","value":"TEST01"}



How do create a column for each attribute and convert the values to strings?



Row
Invoice Number
Account Number




1
27224 & 27225
TEST01



